# How to pass data from controller to router in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have folder diagram where i have two files controller and router , Now i have pulled the data from mongodb in controller that i am trying to pass it router so i can send it to client using api but i am failed to get response in router , any idea what is implemented wrong.

I mentioned folder `diagram` because this router is just for this particular model that will send response regarding diagram only.

diagram.controller.js

```
var Diagram = require('./diagram.model');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = function index() {
       Diagram.find({}, function(err, res) {
         if (!err) {
           console.log('Response from controller', res);
           return res;
         }
       });
     }
```

diagram.router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./diagram.controller');

var router = express.Router();

console.log('THis is in router',controller.index());
router.get('/getAllDiagram',controller.index());

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to modify your code a little bit.

The first aspect that has to be changed is the way how you pass the `index` function to the router. Please make sure that you don't execute it directly. This function will be called by `express` when a request hits your server at the particular route.

*diagram.router.js*

```
router.get('/getAllDiagram', controller.index);
```

The next change is in the `index` function itself. The function gets two parameters by `express`: `req` - the request object and `res` - the response object:

*diagram.controller.js*

```
module.exports.index = function index(req, res) {
    Diagram.find({}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Something bad happened: ' + err.message);

            return res.status(500);
        }

        console.log('Response from controller', result);
        res.json(result);
    });
};
```

Please note that I renamed your variable `res` to `result`.

Comment: Have you renamed the variable in `Diagram.find({}, function(err, result)` to `result`? Otherwise, it gets overwritten which results in the stated exception.

Comment: Okay, can you paste your code into a Gist and post it here?

Comment: dont have access to gist

Comment: The code in the answer is correct so far. Any chance to post yours somewhere? Pastebin, etc.?