# How to pass json object from controller to router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a data in controller from mongodb now i want to send this json object to router so i can send to client side using api , with below code i am getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined` Any idea what is implemented wrong ?

controller.js

```
var Diagram = require('./diagram.model');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function index(req,res) {
       Diagram.find({}, function(err, result) {
         if (!err) {
           console.log('Response from controller', result);
           return res.json(result);
         }
       });
     }
```

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./diagram.controller');
var router = express.Router();
console.log('THis is in router',controller.index);
router.get('/getAllDiagram',controller.index);
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hm, what was wrong with my answer yesterday? :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/39966173/6945467 – Despite that, you have an error in your `modules.exports`. It has to be `module.exports.index = function index(req,res)`. Otherwise there would not be an `index` function on `controller`.

Comment: I still could not solve the problem and SO want us to avoid for further conversation and i can not access chat, so i asked new question with new tags.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log('THis is in router',controller.index);` ?

Comment: i have problem in controller line `res.json(result)` its not in router yet.

Comment: @hussain you need to replace `module.exports = function index(req,res) {` with `module.exports.index = function (req,res) {` I think this will fix issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `module.exports` (see my comment above) is the problem. What do you think about writing your request handling straightforward first (so that you have a feeling of success (: ):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/getAllDiagram', (req, res) => {
     Diagram.find({}, function(err, result) {
         if (err) {
             console.error(`Error in finding diagram: ${err.message}`);

             return res.status(500);
         }

         res.json(result);
     });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

**Advanced version**

*controller.js*

```
const Diagram = require('./diagram.model');

module.exports.index = (req, res) => {
    Diagram.find({}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(`Error in finding diagram: ${err.message}`);

            return res.status(500);
        }

        res.json(result);
    });
};
```

*router.js*

```
const express = require('express');

const controller = require('./controller');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/getAllDiagram', controller.index);

module.exports = router;
```

*app.js*

```
const express = require('express');

const router = require('./router');

const app = express();

app.use(router);

app.listen(8080);
```

*Important:* Please check the `module.exports.index` declaration. That was wrong in your code snippet.

Comment: i tried and I know i can get data with this approach but i have to follow the way code is structured. I need to have controller that pass data to router.

Comment: Okay, so I appended an "advanced version" which I tried on my local machine and it works like a charm (without the model handling of course).

Comment: this time i did not see any error but how can i see if i get data in router ?

Comment: @hussain What do you mean with "how can i see if i get data in router"? You have to send a HTTP request to the particular URL. Have you mounted your router to your "express" app?

Comment: I want to see data in router.js so i can send it to client , what you mean by mounted your router to express app ?

Comment: `res.json` is responsible for sending the data straight to the client. Executing this line will "end" the HTTP response and sends it back to the client. I updated my answer so that you can see what I mean by "mounting" the router. You can find more information about the routing mechanisms in `express` here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125423/discussion-between-notion-and-hussain).

Comment: Wohoo! Glad I could help!